# Find my prefix, suffix and infix on the web page

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> Look at this for my prefix.
> Look above this for my suffix.
> Look under this for my infix.
> Yes, on the web page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Postage

Look at this for my prefix.

> Post

Look above this for my suffix.

> Age

Look under this for my infix.

> Tag

Yes, on the web page.

> I think this just ties in the fact that each line is literal rather than hinting at the overall answer (which I thought initially). Although maybe "postage" is slang for content that is posted?

Hints (given in comments)

> Refers to creation date, tags, mail (directly) and has the form p******